# Copy curl command to python

Tags: python, curl

I upload picture to imgbb.com site and show the curl command using firefox

```
curl "https://imgbb.com/json" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------270624834321652808912303071412" -H "Origin: https://imgbb.com" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: https://imgbb.com/" -H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=6o18hipgu8uk8orq4pg47of4b5; __gads=ID=40783678319bf866-227f347cf1a6003f:T=1614875864:RT=1614875864:S=ALNI_MbBjogRusDweg41MHFP01KawfJuiw" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Sec-GPC: 1" -H "TE: Trailers" --data-binary "-----------------------------270624834321652808912303071412"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""source""; filename=""test.png"""^

"Content-Type: image/png"^

""^

"-----------------------------270624834321652808912303071412"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""type"""^

""^

"file"^

"-----------------------------270624834321652808912303071412"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""action"""^

""^

"upload"^

"-----------------------------270624834321652808912303071412"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""timestamp"""^

""^

"1614875900988"^

"-----------------------------270624834321652808912303071412"^

"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""auth_token"""^

""^

"e47e40461c19ef13a3768c45e2a0a5189f3bf625"^

"-----------------------------270624834321652808912303071412--"^

""
```

I can see `test.png` picture that I upload .

How can I send that command again using python with different picture?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use the [online `curl` to Python `requests` generator](https://curl.trillworks.com/).

But you should really be using the [imgBB API](https://api.imgbb.com/) instead.

Comment: Is there any offline tool to convert curl to requests python ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. I think it'd be best to just use the API.